# Using both ActiveMQ Artemis and ActiveMQ Classic in the same Spring Boot application

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-artemis

I need to implement a Spring Boot 3.0.2 application using both ActiveMQ Artemis and ActiveMQ Classic 5.18.
ActiveMQ Artemis already woks, but I cannot create an ActiveMQ Classic connection because its timed out.

I use an ActiveMQ Artemis in Docker built by Dockerfile and an ActiveMQ Classic based on `symptoma/activemq:latest`. The web interface works well in both brokers.

docker-compose snippets:

```
  activemq:
    image: symptoma/activemq:latest
    restart: always
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - activemq
    ports:
      - 61615:61616
      - 8162:8161
    environment:
      - ACTIVEMQ_DISALLOW_WEBCONSOLE=false
      - ACTIVEMQ_USER=activemq_user
      - ACTIVEMQ_PASSWORD=activemq_pwd
      - ACTIVEMQ_WEBADMIN_USERNAME=webadmin
      - ACTIVEMQ_WEBADMIN_PASSWORD=webadmin123
```

dependencies:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-artemis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

ActiveMQ parameters are in `application.yaml` like this:

```
spring:
  activemq:
    broker-url: tcp://localhost:61615  # Artemis are in 61616
    user: activemq-user
    password: activemq-pwd
```

I try to create a `ConnectionFactory` like this:

```java
@Configuration
@Slf4j
@EnableJms
public class JMSConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = "cbsConnectionFactory")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.activemq")
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        return new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
    }

    @Bean(name="cbsJmsTemplate")
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() {
        return new JmsTemplate(connectionFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter cbsUpdateAgentStateMessageConverter(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        return new JSONMessageConverter(objectMapper, UpdateAgentStateData.class);
    }

    @Bean(name = "cbsListenerContainerFactory")
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> cbsListenerContainerFactory() {
        SimpleJmsListenerContainerFactory factory=new SimpleJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        return factory;
    }
}
```

I try to send a message to a queue like this:

```java
@Component
@Slf4j
public class CbsUpdateAgentStateConsumer {

    private final JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @Autowired
    CbsUpdateAgentStateConsumer(@Qualifier("cbsJmsTemplate") JmsTemplate jmsTemplate) {
        this.jmsTemplate=jmsTemplate;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        this.jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("asd", "asdm");
    }

    @JmsListener(destination = "asd", containerFactory = "cbsListenerContainerFactory")
    public void receiveMessage(String message) {
        log.debug(String.format("Enter receiveMessage, message:%s", message));
    }
}
```

the error of `convertAndSend` is:

```
Uncategorized exception occurred during JMS processing; nested exception is ActiveMQConnectionTimedOutException[errorType=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT message=AMQ219013: Timed out waiting to receive cluster topology. Group:null]
```

When I use additional ActiveMQ Classic dependency like:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

I've got another error:

```
ERROR o.a.a.a.c.client - AMQ214013: Failed to decode packet
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AMQ219032: Invalid type: 1
```

How can I use both brokers in the same application?

Comment: If you're going to do something that complicated then use the client libraries.

Comment: The error from `convertAndSend` indicates the ActiveMQ Artemis core JMS client is failing to connect. It's probably pointed at ActiveMQ "Classic" which doesn't support the core protocol. The second error (i.e. `AMQ214013`) looks like another protocol mismatch reported by ActiveMQ Artemis. Perhaps the ActiveMQ "Classic" OpenWire JMS client is attempting to connect to an acceptor on ActiveMQ Artemis which isn't configured to support OpenWire.

Comment: What exactly is the use-case here? Which clients are connecting to which broker?

Comment: This is only for ActiveMQ, Artemis part is working well. JmsTemplate has a qualifier identify cbsJmsTemplate. cbsJmsTemplate using connectionFactory qualified cbsConnectionFactory, which is working with activeMQ properties. I've debugged the code and jmsTemplate assigned the activeMQ connections.

Comment: Well something doesn't appear to be working as you expect because both of those errors (i.e. `AMQ219013` and `AMQ214013`) are coming from ActiveMQ _Artemis_ code.

Comment: Also, it's worth noting that ActiveMQ Artemis is an ActiveMQ broker so for the sake of this discussion it's ambiguous to just say "ActiveMQ." You need to be specific about _which_ ActiveMQ broker you referring to (i.e. "Classic" or Artemis).

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. There are two `ActiveMQConnectionFactory` classes, one in `org.apache.activemq` package (from `spring-boot-starter-activemq`) and another in `org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client` package (from `spring-boot-starter-artemis`).

For ActiveMQ Classic I need to use `ActiveMQConnectionFactory` from `org.apache.activemq`.